# awscli doesnt work on WSL2

Tags: amazon-web-services, wsl2

I managed to install awscli on WSL1. I can query my s3 bucket, copy and move data to/from my buckets just fine. However, when I convert to WSL2, awscli doesnt seem to work. If I issue

```
aws s3 ls
```

I would get

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

I tried different region, and it would fail. But as soon as I convert back to WSL1, it would work again.

How can I get my awscli to work on WSL2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there's no network connection at all. Not just awscli issue. After the upgrade to WSL2, I need to shutdown the instance by running

```
wsl --shutdown
```

and restart the instance back up. after that it works perfectly

Comment: this worked for me..the error i had was "an error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials." I shutdown wsl .. onnected to my windows 11 wsl2 ubuntu 22.04 and aws cli works now!